# Azure DevOps: How can I spin a container up in order to run tests?

Tags: docker, azure-devops

On Docker Hub I have an image; I instantiate it from an Azure DevOps pipeline in order to run tests. After the tests are completed I shut down the container and remove it.

When I instantiate a container from that image I also need to bind some volumes.

Can I use docker-compose to get the volumes from the Azure DevOps repository? Or is it suggested that I switch to AKS for this task?

Comment: there are multiple ways to run containers on Azure: Azure Web Apps for Containers, Azure Container Instances, Azure Kubernetes Service. If your solution needs more than one image, then you'll need an orchestrator.

Comment: I need a single image but I need to mount volumes. Which one is the quicker to implement?

Comment: Azure Container Instances

Comment: ACI is overkill. You can use a `container` resource in a YAML pipeline to start a sidecar container. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-containers

Answer (score 1):

This is natively supported in Azure DevOps YAML pipelines and can be achieved in a few lines of YAML with a [`container`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-containers) resource.

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: string  # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
    image: string  # container image name
    options: string  # arguments to pass to container at startup
    endpoint: string  # reference to a service connection for the private registry
    env: { string: string }  # list of environment variables to add
    ports: [ string ] # ports to expose on the container
    volumes: [ string ] # volumes to mount on the container
    mapDockerSocket: bool # whether to map in the Docker daemon socket; defaults to true
    mountReadOnly:  # volumes to mount read-only - all default to false
      externals: boolean  # components required to talk to the agent
      tasks: boolean  # tasks required by the job
      tools: boolean  # installable tools like Python and Ruby
      work: boolean # the work directory
```

Comment: I can't find documentation on where volume sources can be located. Can they be located on the DevOps repository?  I have a couple of files in the repository I need to mount as volumes but it's not clear to me if I can use them from there or put them on some other cloud resource

Comment: @AlessioMarchetti The volume sources are any path within the pipeline's context. If you need files from a repo, ensure the repo is cloned and the files are available.